# Select first of each IGrouping, aggregating some properties without explicitly assigning each non-aggregated property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to select the first element of each `IGrouping` while aggregating some properties without explicitly assigning each non-aggregated property in the projection?

For example, `SelectAggregatedFirstsOfMyThings()` is doing what I want. However, in my real-world scenario, `MyThing` has something like 30 properties. I want to carry over the property values of the first in each `IGrouping` without explicitly declaring `MyIntA = x.First().MyIntA` for each of the non-aggregated properties. Is there some other shorthand syntax for achieving this (without pulling in something like Automapper)?

```
public class MyThing {

    public int MyFkId { get; set; }
    public int MyIntA { get; set; }
    public int MyIntB { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate {get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyCaller {
    public IQueryable<MyThing> SelectAggregatedFirstsOfMyThings(IOrderedQueryable<MyThing> myThings) =>
        myThings.GroupBy(t => t.MyFkId)
                .Select(g => new MyThing
                {
                    MyIntA = g.First().MyIntA,
                    MyIntB = g.First().MyIntB,
                    MyDate = g.Max(d => d.MyDate)
                    ...
                }
}
```

Comment: How should your program guess how to aggregate a colum? So how should it know if you want the `Max`-value for `MyDate`, but the first for `MyIntA`? Or do you just want to omit the property name within your anonmyous type? Like `new MyThing { g.First().MyIntA }`? Then you´d have to create an instance of an anonymous type, which I´m not sure EF supports.

Comment: The default is to use `First()` for all properties. I only want to apply aggregations like `Max()` to a couple of the properties. Maybe I can `Select()` the firsts of the entire objects, and then apply the aggregations after the `Select()` somehow? Note that this is not EF-specific, just generic LINQ (I think). We're actually using LINQ-to-SQL (sadly).

Comment: You can always take the cheap and dirty route and serialize/deserialize the object(For a deep copy), and then change the properties you wish to on the copy.

Comment: hrm... thanks, @Dan, but that seems like a potential perf issue. probably best to explicitly assign each property before going down that path, I think.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett You could also explore faster DeepCopy implementations if you are in a perf critical area.  But aside from implementing a DeepCopy of some sort, yeah you will be stuck with explicit assignment.

Comment: You mean something like .Select({g => new g.First(), MyDate=g.Max(d.MyDate)}).Select(gg=> new MyThing{MyIntA = gg.g.MyIntA, MyDate=gg.g.MyDate})?

Comment: thanks, @klabranche , but I think that would still require all of the explicit assignments for each property (like `MyIntA = gg.g.MyIntA`), which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Gotcha, your going to have to explicit assign as some point though.... it's just a matter of when.  You could certainly change MyThing to accept the whole object but that just means at usage time you use mything.g.prop.  Automapper just does this auto assign for you using conventions but it's still doing the boring explicit assignment.  :-)  EF does allow for dynamics but I don't remember if LinqToSql does but I don't see why not.... That would be your only other way but not likely what you want.  OR use something like dapper micro orm.  It will do this auto assignment for you like automapper.

Comment: I think your best bet is to include `FirstMyThing = g.First()` and access those non-aggregated properties off of `FirstMyThing`.

Comment: @NetMage , Gotchya, so to do that, I'd have to save off `g` in a temporary local var in order to access it to calculate the aggregates. Then, rejoin with the `.First()`-ed collection. That could work...

Comment: No, I was thinking more like `.Select(g => new MyThing
                {
                    FirstMyThing = g.First(),
                    MyDate = g.Max(d => d.MyDate)
                    ...
                }
}`

Comment: @NetMage hmm, but `MyThing` doesn't have a property on it of type `MyThing`. So,  `FirstMyThing = g.First()` throws a compilation error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, that only applies if you are using an anonymous object.

Comment: What about if you created the `MyThing` from `g.First()` and then overwrote the aggregate fields: `.Select(g => { var r = new MyThing(g.First()); r.MyDate = g.Max(d => d.MyDate); ...; return r; })`  ?

Comment: @NetMage That one looked real promising, but since I am using Linq-to-Sql, I get `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.`

Comment: Consider putting in `AsEnumerable()` just before the Select to pull over objects and then convert on the client side?

Comment: @NetMage Nice, I think that does it. I've actually went down a completely separate path to solve my issue, but if you want to post an answer combining your last two comments, I'll accept it. Great to know for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a statement lambda to create a new `MyThing` initialized from the `First()` of the group, and then re-assign the aggregated properties to create the object you want. Since you are using LINQ to SQL, you must pull (instantiate) the query results to the client using `AsEnumerable` before the statement lambda.

```
public IQueryable<MyThing> SelectAggregatedFirstsOfMyThings(IOrderedQueryable<MyThing> myThings) =>
    myThings.GroupBy(t => t.MyFkId)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(g => {
                var r = new MyThing(g.First());
                r.MyDate = g.Max(d => d.MyDate);
                // assign remaining aggregated properties ...
                return r;
             });
```

Comment: Note that this solution (I think) requires `MyThing` to have a constructor with a parameter of an instance of `MyThing`, which is a bit inception-like. Maybe just doing `var r = g.First()` rather than `new`-ing would be better (as long as `r` is never tried to persist back to the db).

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett I expect most objects (perhaps a remnant of my C++ experience?) to have a [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor). I don't think re-assigning a framework created database object is a good idea, because it could have unexpected affects if you do use the context elsewhere to make changes.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett You could also implement the `IClone` interface instead. That may be more .Net idiom.